# Define lifecycle role on aws s3 bucket with terraform - ARN: arn: invalid prefix

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I need to define a life cycle rule on S3 Bucket with transform.

I was following the configurations [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration).
I used "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" as the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket) says

> The lifecycle_rule attribute is deprecated. See aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration for examples with object lifecycle rules.

It looks straightforward.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "my-bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket.id

  rule {
    id = "rule-1"

    expiration {
      days = 31
    }
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this will result with

```
"bucket" (my-bucket) is an invalid ARN: arn: invalid prefix[0m
```

So I tried replacing id with arn as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373524/how-to-add-lifecycle-rules-to-an-s3-bucket-using-terraform)

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "my-bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket.arn

  rule {
    id = "rule-1"

    expiration {
      days = 31
    }
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

Again the same issue (I was expecting the `.arn` to actually render an arn)

Finally, I just went to the AWS Management console and copied the name

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "my-bucket" {
  bucket = "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"

  rule {
    id = "rule-1"

    expiration {
      days = 31
    }
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

Now I get

```
Error: parsing S3 Control Bucket ARN (): unknown format
```

Can anyone provide a working example?

Note: I am using Terraform 1.3.6

Comment: Is there anything specific in the bucket name? Are you using the `prefix` argument instead of the name?

Comment: the bucket name is simple like "something-whatever-something-else" with only letters and '-'. I don't use the prefix, should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of Terraform CLI are you using but this sample works for me:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region                  = "ap-southeast-1"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials" # Location of named profiles inside developer machine
  profile                 = "my-aws-profile" # Provide your AWS CLI named profile
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "main_s3" {
    bucket = "main-s3-for-tf-poc"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "my_bucket_lc" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.main_s3.id

  rule {
    id = "rule-1"

    expiration {
      days = 31
    }
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

Terraform CLI --version output

```bash
terraform --version
Terraform v1.5.2
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.76.1
```

**Comment from the author of the question:**

This answer is correct and worked for me with an older version of Terraform.  The key difference between my code and the example is the usage of '-' instead of '_' so switch from

```
"aws_s3_bucket" "main-s3"
```

to

```
"aws_s3_bucket" "main_s3"
```